# SignalR: How to send data to IConnected.Connect()

Tags: signalr

I implement the `Connect()` method on `IConnected` interface to add new connections to the correct groups. This works well except for one thing: in order to add the user to the correct group, I need to send a value to be read in this method. I tried adding property to the client hub:

```
var uIHub = $.connection.uIHub;
uIHub.SessionType = "Edit";
```

But it's not accessible from the `Connect` method:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Caller.SessionType) || Caller.SessionType == "Edit") {
     sessionId = WAFContext.EditSession.SessionId.ToString();                
} else {
     sessionId = WAFContext.ViewSession.SessionId.ToString();
}
Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, sessionId);
```

`Caller.SessionType` is always null.

Any suggestions on how to solve this?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I solved this by adding my information to the querystring, which is available on the `IConnected.Connect()` method.

On the .NET client you pass the querystring into your `HubConnection`:

```
var connection = new HubConnection("http://localhost:8080/", "myInfo=12345");
```

On the JS client, you set the `qs` property before starting the connection:

```
$.connection.hub.qs = "myInfo=12345";
```

You can then access this information on the server in the `Connect()` method:

```
var myInfo = Context.QueryString["myInfo"];
Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, myInfo);
```

Comment: Do you know how to do the same with the javascript client? I've tried the following, but it's not working: 

var connection = $.connection("http://localhost:61806/" , "sessionType=visit");
    var uIHub = connection.uIHub;

Comment: This should work: `$.connection.hub.qs = "myInfo=12345"; $.connection.hub.start();`

Comment: @akoeplinger is it safe to pass userid and username parameters in this way ? Can cause any security problem?

Comment: @freshblood It's no different than the security concerns that you'd have if you were passing it through a form on the page; if you're not doing it behind https, then you have a huge security hole.

Comment: I used your suggested approach to pass data, when I'm using IE it's not passed with Unicode and this is what I get on the server: "������". Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: Does Reconnect also receive the data from QueryString?