# Get full URL inside SignalR hub

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, signalr, signalr-hub

I'm developing an user tracking solution using SignalR, as a fun project to learn SignalR, for ASP.NET MVC applications.

Currently i can track logged users and how long are they on a specific page. If they move to another page i track that also and the timer that SignalR is updating resets... Many other features are implemented or partially implemented.

The problem i'm facing is how to get the full url Controller/Action/Parameters
inside SignalR hub?

When i use `HttpContext.Current.Request.Url` the url is always **/signalr/connect**.

NOTE:

```
var hub = $.connection.myHub;
$.connection.hub.start();
```

is in the _Layout.cshtml.

**UPDATE:**

I've tried to use

```
var location = '@HttpContext.Current.Request.Url';
var hub = $.connection.myHub;
$.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
    hub.setLocation(location);
});
```

And the location is passed correctly but I need it on the Connect() task not later.
Is it possible to do this?

**UPDATE 2:**

This approach doesn't work

```
var hub = $.connection.myHub;
$.connection.hub.start(function(){hub.setLocation(location)});
```

as the `Connect()` is called before.

In my hub i have several methods but i would like pass a value (in my case a location) to the `Connect()`, is that possible?

```
public class MyHub : Hub, IDisconnect, IConnected
{  
    public Task Connect()
    {
       //do stuff here
       //and i would like to have the **location** value
    } 

    public Task Disconnect()
    {
       //do stuff here            
    }             
}
```

**Update 3**

Use QueryString to pass data before the `Connect()` occurs.

```
var location = '@HttpContext.Current.Request.Url';

var hub = $.connection.myHub;
$.connection.hub.qs = "location= + location;
$.connection.hub.start();
```

Comment: hello ... are you still working on this tracking solution ... do you mind sharing its code?

Comment: @jalchr I don't mind but the NDA would ;( I will kindly help/point in right direction if you have any questions.

Comment: tip: for user tracking you need to make sure SignalR connects immediately before the page has fully loaded all resources : `waitForPageLoad` so make sure you set that : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32856436/signalr-is-slow-to-connect-from-javascript-client/32856492#32856492

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Passing data like your location value to Connect() is possible via a querystring parameter: [SignalR: How to send data to IConnected.Connect()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12473030/signalr-how-to-send-data-to-iconnected-connect/12473555#12473555)

Comment: Thanks. I really don't know how Google or Stackoverflow suggestions didn't lead me to your answer.

Answer (score 4):

Using query-string is not very secure, cause a hacker can forge JS code and send you wrong location breaking whatever logic you have behind it.

You can try to get this from owin-enviromment variables

`var underlyingHttpContext =
    Context.Request.Environment[typeof(HttpContextBase).FullName] as HttpContextBase;`

Then extract whatever you need.

It will work on IIS, for non-IIS hosting look for other OWIN stuff https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetKatana/wiki/OWIN-Keys

Answer (score 1):

You could pass it from your client js call to your hub as a parameter.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've updated the question. Any solution to this problem?

Comment: can you not put it in start(), is that early enough.  e.g. hub.start(funcoint () { hub.setLocation(location); })  rather than at done.

Comment: Connect() task, I'm not clear when you exactly mean with this.