# In C# MVC4 how to get the server path?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

In c# MVC4 how to I get the server path. for example: `http://192.169.1.120:60632`

Is there a helper function that I can convert something like `~/aFolder/file.htm` into an absolute path? Ideally I would like a way of taking any given url and convert into a full absolute url. E.g. can cope with..

- /aFolder/file.html         -> `http://192.169.1.120:60632/aFolder/file.html`
- http://website.com/file.html     -> `http://website.com/file.html`

And will work anywhere within the c# code - i.e. in a action controller, signalR hub, model etc.

And it will still work when I deploy to a remote server.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `Request.Url` property available in `Controller`. This returns a [Uri](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx) object containing info on the request. From there, you can access the `AbsoluteUri` and `Port` properties to get the info that you need.

If you are interested in getting the url info from SignalR, try looking at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13193606/51) and [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12473555/51).

Comment: Thanks, I should have said I am inside the signalR hub controller. ALso I was hoping for a way of getting the whole thing rather than assembling it form the bits.

Comment: Well, that would definitely have been some relevant information to provide in your question. And it is so hard to do something like `string.Format("{0}:{1}", Request.Url.AbsoluteUri, Request.Url.Port)` ?

Comment: I wasnt sure if the port still existed when deployed

Comment: @spiderplant0 - Can you please explain what exactly is "when deployed" and "has to work anywhere"? I realize SignalR may not be working with a Request/Response model, but it still isn't *anywhere*.

Comment: sorry just new to MVC4. By deployed I mean when hosted on the server. I imagined the absolute path would then be `http://something.com/aFolder`. So no port?

Answer (score 2):

Try this one,

`System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"~/FolderName")`

You can try these as well

`string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetData("FolderName").ToString();`
`HostingEnvironment.MapPath(@"~/FoldeName");`

Comment: Doesn't that give you the local file path, i.e. `D:\some\folder\FolderName` ?

Comment: YOU MUST **NEVER** USE System.Web.HttpContext.Current IN AN MVC PROJECT.

Comment: But your answer is nearly correct. In an action method, use the Server property Server.MapPath("~/FolderName").

Comment: @Softlion Why must you never use `System.Web.HttpContext.Current` ? Not arguing, genuinely asking.

Comment: In MVC, this method does NOT return the correct context. In MVC, the context is an HttpContextBase derived object. System.Web.HttpContext.Current does not inherit from HttpContextBase. If you use System.Web.HttpContext.Current in a worker thread, it will return null. If you use it in a signalr hub it will return null. System.Web.HttpContext.Current can not mocked, can not be overriden ... it is the inheritence of a static past ... now replaced by MVC.

Comment: @Softlion What is the MVC equivalent of `HttpContext.Current`, if any?

Comment: There is none. It should be a parameter of your methods. In any action method you'll get it using the Controller instance base property "HttpContext".

Answer (score 0):

In MVC, you can get a fully qualified URL using the fourth parameter of `Url.Action` - `protocol`:

```
Url.Action("Index", "Home", null, Request.Url.Scheme)
```

Comment: thanks, sorry should have said has to work anywhere, not just in action method